# Help me compile my autoincrement trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I try to compile the following Oracle code:

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
    id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, /* what if two authors have the same name! */
    name VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL
);
/* autoinrement sequence */
CREATE SEQUENCE authors_id_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
/* trigger run before every insert into authors table - copies MySQL autoincrement */
CREATE TRIGGER authors_insert_trg BEFORE INSERT ON authors 
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.id IS NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT authors_id_seq.nextval INTO :new.id FROM FUAL;
END;
```

It says:

```
table AUTHORS created.
sequence AUTHORS_ID_SEQ created.
TRIGGER authors_insert_trg compiled
Warning: execution completed with warning
```

I cannot see any error. Could somebody please help me out?

Comment: Typo: `FROM FUAL` should be `FROM DUAL`; dunno if that's the source of your issue though.  Using a SELECT ... INTO strikes my as odd vs using an INSERT, but I seldom use triggers.

Comment: @OMG Ponies Yes that was the problem. Please post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo: `FROM FUAL` should be `FROM DUAL`